# Login into Stack Exchange using a Windows Live Login

Tags: feature-request, login

I want to ask to incorporate Windows Live ID (.outlook.com or .live.com) for Stack Exchange websites. Windows Live ID is very popular these days.

Comment: I login into feedly.com using my Windows Live ID, so it is possible.

Comment: This is a dupe but I can't find a close target... it might be over on meta.so.  Essentially, the windows live login doesn't support oauth 2.0, which is what SE uses (iirc for both).

Comment: Interesting!. I had searched and did not see this post as a result. Thank you anyway.